# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentUserAsync' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug my react-native app using 'Debug in Exponent'
and I got this error where the packager is starting successfully but with the error in the console

Configurations are:

VSCODE Version: 1.35.1

React-Native VS Code extension version:  0.10.2

Node.js: 10.2.0

OS: Linux x64 4.4.0-154-generic

Expo: 2.21.1

I have tried upgrading and downgrading the vscode.
deleted the node_module and installed npm again.
I even cleared out all the settings and created the fresh launch.json in .vscode so far with no success

error in console is as follows

```
[Info] Making sure your project uses the correct dependencies for Expo. This may take a while...

Checking if this is Expo app......
[Info] Packager is already running.

[Info] Prewarming bundle cache. This may take a while ...

[Info] Building and running application.

[Error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentUserAsync' of undefined
```

Comment: What command causes an error?

Comment: well when I try to start debugger by clicking the green play button, above mentioned error occurs in the console.

Comment: The temporary workaround is described here which worked for me..https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary workaround is [described here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1060) which worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

Same problem occurs with the configuration below :

VSCODE Version: 1.36.1

React-Native VS Code extension version: 0.10.2

Node.js: 10.15.1

OS: Win32 x64

Expo: 3.0.2

Comment: I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 X64 running 

NodeJS 10.15.1
Expo 3.0.2
VSCODE Version: 1.36.1
React-Native VS Code extension version: 0.10.2

Even if I start a new project with Expo init, I couldn't debug it.